# Minimum nodes cross

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table

```
test (node, border)
A  B
A  C
A  E
A  F
F  C
F  D
B  S
```

I need to get an output in form (node, border, num_passes). For. ex. rom A to S, I can get in 2 crosses (A-B-S) and so on. Couldn't understand, how to implement recursive query in sql

Answer (score 0):

Level is what you look for!

```
SELECT node,border,SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (node,'-') || '-' ||border,level
FROM TEST
START WITH NODE= 'A'
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
PRIOR border = NODE;
```

[Result:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8c7e6/16)

```
NODE   BORDER   SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(NODE,'-')||'-'||BORDER    LEVEL

A      B        -A-B                                          1 
B      S        -A-B-S                                        2 
A      C        -A-C                                          1 
A      E        -A-E                                          1 
A      F        -A-F                                          1 
F      C        -A-F-C                                        2 
F      D        -A-F-D                                        2
```

Comment: But as far as I understood, LEVEL will give all possible path betweet two nodes, how can I find the minimum one?

Comment: For example, in your result table - from F to C - it is 2, but should be 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
with tab as (
select 'A' node,  'B' border from dual
union all select 'A',  'C' from dual
union all select 'A', 'E' from dual
union all select 'A', 'F' from dual
union all select 'F', 'C' from dual
union all select 'F', 'D' from dual
union all select 'B', 'S' from dual
)
*/
select node, border, min(length(regexp_replace(s, '[^,]'))) 
from (
select node, border,
       substr(path, instr(path, ',' || node || ',') + length(node)+1, 
                    instr(path, ',' || border || ',') 
                    - instr(path, ',' || node || ',') - length(border)) s from
(select distinct t1.node, t2.border
 from tab t1 cross join tab t2) ab
 join
(select sys_connect_by_path(node, ',') || ',' || border || ',' path from tab
 connect by nocycle node = prior border) dist
 on path like '%,'|| node || ',%'
    and instr(path, ',' || node || ',') > 0
    and instr(path, ',' || node || ',') < instr(path, ',' || border || ',')
)    
group by node, border;
```

Comment: this is the actual thing I need, but when I try to run this query on my real data, that is around 200 rows*2 cols. and in each cell there is varchar of 2 chars. It compiles endless((